# Adding an graphic Interface for a Gnu/linux bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

I try to execute a bash script which works totally fine when executed form the shell. However if I try to execute it using my grahpic menu script the execution fails. There must be a problem with the parameters, but I can't find it. For example if I try to execute option one with my gui, the correct strings are saved in the variable, but cd in option 1 won't work.

Code of my main-program which is called getList.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
SourcePath=$1

DestinationPath=$2

DestinationFileName=$3

Option=$4

#Option 1
#Creates a recursive list of all files in a directory and subdirectories, if the destination file already exists, the content will be overwritten 
if [ $Option = 1 ]
then
                cd $DestinationPath        
                ls -1Rasl $SourcePath > $PathDate
                

############################################################################
#Option 2
#Creates a recursive list of files in a directory and subdirectory including files in archives and prints it  
elif [ $Option = 2 ]
then
                MakeFileListAndPrint

############################################################################
#Option 3
#Recursive search for a file name in all files including archives, prints all found macthes with path
else 
        MakeFileList 
        grep -H $SearchFile $PathDate  

fi
```

GUI-CODE:

```
#! /bin/bash


SourcePath=$(zenity --entry --text "Enter your source path" --title "sourcepath" --entry-text=""); 
DestinationPath=$(zenity --entry --text "Enter your destination path" --title "destination path" --entry-text="");
DestinationFileName=$(zenity --entry --text "Enter your destination file name" --title "destination file name" --$

ask=`zenity --list --title="Choose your Option" --column="0" "1" "2" "3" --width=100 --height=300 --hide-header`

if [ "$ask" == "1" ]; then
    bash ./getList.sh $SourcePath $DestinationPath $DestinationFileName $ask
    
 fi

if [ "$ask" == "2" ]; then
    bash ./getList.sh $SourcePath $DestinationPath $DestinationFileName $ask
fi

if [ "$ask" == "3" ]; then
    SearchFile=$(zenity --entry --text "Enter your search term" --title "search term" --entry-text="");
    bash ./getList.sh $SourcePath $DestinationPath $DestinationFileName $ask $SearchFile
fi
```

Output with echo statements with these given parameters:
bash menu $1=~/test $2=~/Destination $3=testfile $4=1

```
user:~/debug$ bash menu.sh 
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Sourcepath in menu is: ~/test 
DestinationPath in menu is ~/Destination 
Destination Filename in Menu is: testfile 
option 1 is executed
DestinationPath in getList is: ~/Destination
PWD bevor change dir user/debug
./getList.sh: line 85: cd: ~/Destination: No such file or directory
PWD after change dir user/debug
./getList.sh: line 87: ~/Destination/testfile: No such file or directory
PWD after Rasl user/debug
program executed
user:~/debug$
```

Comment: Maybe you already have, but could you add a debug log to your bash script?

Comment: Actually I haven't ! I am relatively new to Gnu/Linux and didn't now about debug logs, but it totally makes sense that something like this would exist. May I ask if you could recommend a website where I can read about it? Ofc I will do research by myself but maybe there is some good explanation out there :)

Comment: @Mooon, just put `echo` statements with relevant variables to print out what is happening...

Comment: I see, actually I did that already, I will add it to the post then

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `~` is not expanded. This works:

```
cd ~
```

But puting a tilde (`~`) to zenity would be returned in double-quotes, just  try this, entering just the tilde:

```
cd $(zenity --entry)
```

It is the same as

```
$ cd "~"
bash: cd: ~: No such file or directory
```

This worked for me to re-trigger the bash expansion:

```
x=$(zenity --entry)
cd $(eval echo $x)
```

However this is not safe! If the user would put some dangerous code to x, it would be evaluated! This is somewhat better:

```
cd $(echo $x | sed "s:~:$HOME:")
```

This exploits this simple difference:

```sh
$ echo ~ $HOME
/home/roman /home/roman
$ echo "~ $HOME"
~ /home/roman
$ echo '~ $HOME'
~ $HOME
```

Comment: I am not quiet sure what " `~` is not expanded" means. Is the problem related to that question? -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/481715/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script   Or is more like the visibility/expansion of the parameters? Anyways, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Mooon, `~` is not any directory on your hard-drive, it is a shortcut, that is "expanded" to the path to your home directory. `*` is also expanded to the list of all items in some directory. Try in non-empty directory run `echo *` and `echo "*"` to see the difference. The question you have linked is not related to this at all.